# What is the best way to implement the complex circular charts (d3.js?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

I am trying to implement a chart something like this [image]

I wanted to know id d3.js library would allow me to plot such kind of graphs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you got so far? If you haven't tried anything yet check out the [wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) give it and go and come back with any problems.

Comment: Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/frankieali4/pen/GIhtd) with code you can play with.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a library, [Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp) can draw the graph, animate it, scale it, or anything you might need fairly easily. The [Arc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arc.asp) method is particularly relevant.

```
ctx.beginPath();
//Start the arc at 90 degrees, aka the bottom.
//End the arc at 360 - (360 degrees * 46% expressed as 0.46) + our starting 90 degrees.
//Pi/180 converts degrees to radians.
ctx.arc(64,64,32,284.4*(Math.PI/180),90*(Math.PI/180));
ctx.lineWidth=8;
ctx.strokeStyle="green"
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Tried doing this... didnt seem to work... could you shed more light on it ? Since there will be overlapping arcs too.... if you see carefully, on top of the outermost arc, there are two other arcs

Answer (score 1):

If somebody's still looking for this, here's the entire thing. Just use HTML 5 canvas tag and use it's 2D context to draw. Drawing part is in JS.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 1.5 * Math.PI, .5 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.lineWidth=8;
ctx.strokeStyle="green";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 42, 1.5 * Math.PI, .7 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.lineWidth=8;
ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 34, 1.5 * Math.PI, .6 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.lineWidth=8;
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```